# JQuery Hide rows (by attribute) when combobox value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a blocks dropdown. When the blocks dropdown is changed, I would like to hide the rows with a blockID attribute value not equal to the selected block option value.

```
<TR>
<td>
<A HREF="#" class="link" id="102" sensorid="102" sensortype="1" sensorname="Thermistor"equipid="74" equipname="1535 NW" equiptype="1" equiptypename="Sensors" modeltype="1" modeltypename="Point Six" controlled="f" serialno="7054103C00000000" active="f" fieldID="1" blockID="10">
102</A>
</td>
<td>Thermistor</td><td>1535 NW</td><td>Sensors</td><td>Point Six</td><td>No</td><td>7054103C00000000</td><td>No</td>
</TR>

$('#cmbBlockID').change(function(){
    $("tr").show();
    cmbBlkID = $("#cmbBlockID").prop("value");
    if (cmbBlkID != 0){
            $("a[blockID!='"+cmbBlkID+"']").closest("tr").hide();//the line in question
    }
});
```

I am getting inconsistent results. Is there a better way to write the line to hide some of the rows without using "closest"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#cmbBlockID').change(function(){
    $("tr").show();
    cmbBlkID = $("#cmbBlockID").val();

    if (cmbBlkID != 0){
        $("a[blockID!='"+cmbBlkID+"']").parent().parent().hide();
        // or
        $("tr").find('a').not('[blockID='"+cmbBlkID+"']').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joao! At least I can eliminate this chunk of code as the problem. Alas, the problem lies elsewhere . . .